# CSS margin-top in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, margin

[image]

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div style="height: 350px; width: 250px; background-color: #ECECEA; color: #993399">
        <div class="image">
            <asp:Image ID="imgteacher" runat="server" Height="150" Width="250" /></div>
        <div style="margin-left: 3px">
            <div style="font-size: 28px">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblname" Text="Mobile Web Development"></asp:Label></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 140px; float: left">
                <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text="01.04.2014"></asp:Label></div>
            <div id="detail" style="margin-top: 150px; font-size: 20px; color: Fuchsia; margin-left: 190px">
                <a href="#">Detail</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am developing in Asp.Net .
I have so problem.
As shown above code `margin-top` for `lbldetail` is `140px`. At this time it is on the bottom of gray window.
But here `lblname` can be change by user.
User can add long name as `lblname`. At this time `lbldetail` goes downwards and exits border of gray window.(if `lblname` would be little , at this time it goes up toward as shown picture)
But I want `lbldetail's` place would not be depend on `lblname` and its place would be constant(bottom of gray window)
I hope I could explain.

Comment: Avoid inline CSS first and start separating a CSS into a separate file, atleast at page level

Comment: can you provide JsFiddle ?

Comment: @Murali Murugesan, I wil do it, but later.
.

Comment: @SpiderCode , no I don't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div with id "detail" needs position absolute. and as [Murali Murugesan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559213/murali-murugesan) said, you do need to lose the inline styles and use a CSS file.

```
div#detail
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:330px; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: Fuchsia; 
    margin-left: 190px
}
```

You can find the example at: http://jsfiddle.net/9Bkha/

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote later because of internet problem.
`Position:absoulte ` , so , it means ` div#detail ` 's place is constant ?

Comment: I set `height` for each `div label#lblname` and `div#detail` place is constant now, but `position:absolute` may be easer way.

Comment: @user3461906 The container needs to have the heiht set and the #detail needs to have the top set accordingly. I don't know any other way to do this, probably with tables, but i don't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you, and I don't use tables.